# How to implement a tableview inside a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to show a tableview within a cell of a tableView. I have a separate dictionary for tableview that is residing inside each cell of tableView. Where i need to assign the dictionary values to the tableview that is inside the cell

Comment: you can use section header for title and rows for dictionary values.

Answer (score 1):

Add the tableView as a subview to the cell. Next assign a delegate/datasource to the tableview. This can be the same object as the outer tableViews datasource/delegate. Every time a delegate method is called, the tableView is send along as a parameter and you can simply do (assuming you have properties for both tableViews):

```
if (tableView == self.outerTableView){
    // ... do stuff for outer tableView
} else if (tableView == self.innerTableView) {
    // ... do stuff for inner tableVIew
}
```

I am assuming here that you have only one cell with one tableView in it. If you have more cells with a tableView in it, the idea can stay the same, except that with many cells with tableViews there is surely a better place to handle the tableViewCallbacks than in the viewController of the outer tableView.

Comment: How can i check the tableview(custom cell of maintableview) in main tableview's view controller

Comment: What do you mean? Find out which of the tableViews is calling the delegate/datasource methods?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific as to what exactly is not working. Can you show code that you think implements the idea I gave you? That way I will be able to tell why it is not working.

Comment: I will share my project if you give me your mail id